# the instruction at x referenced memory at y.The memory could not read

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

When i run this code, computer show memory error

> the instruction at x reference memory at y. The memory could not be read

```
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
class Matrix{
private:
    int row,col,**ptr;
public:
    Matrix();
    void create(int,int);
    void show();
    Matrix multiply(Matrix);
  };
Matrix::Matrix()
{
    row=0;
    col=0;
    ptr=NULL;
}
void Matrix::create(int r,int c)
{
    row=r;
    col=c;
    ptr=new int* [row];
    static srand(time(0));
    for(int i=0;i<row;++i)
    {
        ptr[i]=new int[i+1];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            ptr[i][j]=rand()%6+1;
        }
    }
}
Matrix Matrix::multiply(Matrix obj2)
{
    if(col==obj2.row)
    {
    Matrix temp;
    for(int i=0; i<row; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<obj2.col; ++j)
        {
            temp.ptr[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<obj2.col;j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<col;k++)
            {
            temp.ptr[i][j]+=ptr[i][k]*obj2.ptr[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return temp;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Conditions are NOT fulfill for Multiplication"<<endl;
    }
}
void Matrix::show()
{
    cout<<"Matrix: "<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            cout<<ptr[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
Matrix obj1,obj2,obj3;
obj1.create(2,2);
obj1.show();
obj2.create(2,2);
obj2.show();
obj3=obj1.multiply(obj2);
obj3.show();
}
```

Program should multiply matrix and store in 3rd object, but error occurs.  I don't know where is problem.  That's why i sent whole code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your code should not compile, because `static srand(time(0));` is a syntax error. Please provide the code you actually ran.

Comment: this code is running...it is static so that it produce different value for different objects

Comment: [It shoudn't](https://godbolt.org/z/uxe1ml). Even if you are using an ancient compiler that does allow this syntax or you used a `-fpermissive` compiler flag, it will not be parsed as a call to `srand`. it will define a *new* static variable named `srand` of type `int` and will initialize it with the result of `time(0)`. That `srand` variable will shadow the `srand` function from the standard library in that function. So you would never have called `srand` at all.

Comment: u know better sir...I'm using Dev c++

Comment: I'm new on stack ...so I don't know much about tags and how to explain....in create method..just see code above nd down static stand()...if I make that statement comment program Ran without memory error but output is not produce completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is reading off the end of allocated memory. In your `create` method, you do not allocate enough space to store an entire row of elements:

```cpp
void Matrix::create(int r,int c)
{
    row=r;
    col=c;
    ptr=new int* [row];
    static srand(time(0));
    for(int i=0;i<row;++i)
    {
        ptr[i]=new int[i+1]; // <- the allocation is here
    }
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++) // <- you iterate j from 0 to col here
        {
            ptr[i][j]=rand()%6+1; // <- and then access here
        }
    }
}
```

Since you are allocating i+1 elements, the first row only has enough space for a single element, the second has space for two and so on. Modifying the allocation to make space for `col` elements should fix the issue.